# Clearing text of the TextView closes the app in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have UiTextView i clear the text of that using the following line then the app closes

same code i am writing for other textfield then it works but it works but closes the app.

any idea how to solve this issue.

```
descriptionTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
```

Comment: Have you tried descriptionTextField.text= @"";

Comment: Did u check whether this textfield has been linked properly if it is a outlet or alloc inited properly if you are adding by code. What is the message you get when the app closes.

Comment: @NativeDeveloper I have not down voted your question so before saying please confirm once from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it on background thread. So apple doesn't allow to work with UI in background thread.So please follow me

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(clearTextView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

- (void)clearTextView
{
      descriptionTextField.text = @"";
}
```

Second thing you don't need to use `[NSString stringWithFormat]` method.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: sure i am accetpting it

Answer (score -1):

your are using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]` method to create `NSString`. in this method you have to provide format string and argument values that you are not providing at all. So that is actually a wrong way to make a call of this method.

this is how you can resolve your problem...

First of all check whether your `descriptionTextField` outlet well connect to your `UITestField`,

than you can clear text field as

```
descriptionTextField.text = @"";
```